# When to update state based on previous state in useState hook in React/Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I have seen quiet a few examples on how to update state based on previous state, but I don't see much explanation on when to update state based on previous state, most examples use a counter example, but what if I was setting a object in state, would this still be based on the previous value or can I just update the state. e.g

```
const exampleData = [
    {
       text: 'Example name',
       value: 1
    },
    {
       text: 'Example name 2',
       value: 2
    }
]

  const [asset, setAsset] = useState(exampleData[0]);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
      setAsset(event.target.value) 
  }
```

So in the example I am updating the state in the handleClick function, but would I need to update it based on the previous value or not?

Comment: Is `value: 3` a random choice, or is it dictated by what's currently in the state? Same question for the text, though that seems less likely to be related to the current state.

Comment: So it's the data structure of the `exampleData` but its an example

Comment: I'm asking about the way the new state (`{text: 'update name', value: 3}`) is calculated. Is the new state unrelated to the previous state? Or do you need to use something from the previous state to calculate the new state?

Comment: I have updated the question, the handleClick function would set the state based on the value of the event.target

Comment: Since you want the code to do exactly the same thing regardless of what the previous state was, then your code is fine.

Comment: So, when would you set the state based on previous state?

Comment: If you need to do a calculation with the old state. Eg if you need to increment a counter, or copy/append to an array, or copy/modify an object.

Comment: So for example if a dropdown list was being populated with the `ExampleData`, and the `setAsset` function is setting the state of `asset` with that data value based on the event.target, it's fine to do that and not update based on previous state?

Comment: Write out whatever code you have in mind for calling `setAsset`. If it doesn't make any use of `asset`, you're fine. Using `exampleData` is fine.

Comment: If you add as an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access `previous state`, avaiable in `setState` action

```js
const [state, setState] = useState(false);

const handleClick = () => {
    setState(prev => !prev); // true
    setState(prev => !prev); // false
}
```

**Notice: `setState` is `async` action**

Comment: But when would this be used? in what scenario?

Comment: You can use this scenario `whenever you want to update the state` and access the previous state.